# Database tables relationship foreignkey in dataset1.xsd

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, relational-database

I have add relationship with tables Stock > Products when I register something in the stock table it must show in products table columns: `productName`, `quantityColumn` and `PriceColumn`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stoku] (
[Stock-ID]  INT NOT NULL,
[Customer]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Category] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Product]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Qty]     NUMERIC (18)   NULL,
[Price]     NUMERIC (18)   NULL,
[ProductID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Stoku] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Stock-ID] ASC), 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Stoku_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES produktet(ID)
);
```

Can I create a database diagram in VS2015 because SQL Server 2012 doesn't let me create a diagram. Can someone explain a little bit about the relationship tables have? I watched tutorials but still having a problem binding tables

Comment: I think you have it. The problem is with your ProductID in this table. It is not an identity column here. It is in the produktet table but it is not going to be incremented here in the stoku table.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating both tables without key constraints. Can you then try a join to see if the logic works works and then try adding a foreign key and primary key through SSMS afterwards.

**Edit:**

If you populate both tables with data you can add a join between the stock and products table on stock ID.

To get all records that match on both tables, you would perform an inner join, you can perform different types of join that will return different rows. if you perform a left join instead you can get all records on stock plus matching rows on products.

Try something like this:

**select stock.*, products.* 
from stock inner join products on 
stock.stockId = products.stockId**

If you specify the stock.stockId as a primary key in SSMS and products.stockId as a foreign key you can improve the performance of your queries and also enforce referential integrity, although it is not essential to get your query to work.